# Scrollmagic duration

Tags: scrollmagic

Is there a way to set the scrollmagic duration on a scene as long as the height of the scene? I want to use the class toggles functionality and certain scenes are heigher than the viewport height.

```
<section id="sec1">I'm 400px in height</section>
<section id="sec1">I'm 100% in height (1 viewport)</section>
<section id="sec1">I'm 2500px in height (2,2 viewports)</section>
```

Duration in px: {duration: 400}

Duration in vh: {duration: '100%'}

Duration in element height: ???

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Try not to use an id more than once in your html. You should be using a class instead of an id in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Try using $("#sec1").height() in the duration option.

Comment: This would only work if the id was used one time. This situation looks like it would need a loop, or 3 different scenes.

Answer (score 0):

To make the duration the height of a scene, you would need to find the height of the item, and then apply that to the duration.

Seeing as all your scenes are sections, you could loop through all sections.

```
(function() {
let controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

// Run through all sections
let items = document.querySelectorAll("section");

items.forEach(function(element, index) {
    let height = element.clientHeight; //height of current element
    let scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        duration: height
        //Other scene options go here
    })
        .on("leave enter", function() {
            //Element instructions
        })
        .addTo(controller);
});
```

**Note:** Unless the goal is to give each section their own ID, I would change the ID to class on your sections as pages should only have an ID appear once on the page, while classes can be used multiple times.

[An example of this in use](https://codepen.io/shikkaba/pen/WNNVdgg).